# Why is Osiris-REx using an Earth flyby gravity assist?

Tags: gravity-assist, osiris-rex

Osiris rode on an Atlas V 411. Why not use a larger rocket and skip the gravity assist flyby?

Comment: Because larger rockets cost a lot more? Any particular reason "cost" isn't enough?

Comment: If launches were free, using a higher performance launch vehicle would make sense because the extra year needed to perform the Earth gravity assist would have unnecessarily added a few million dollars to to the cost of the Osiris-REx mission. Launches of course aren't free. Using a sufficiently capable rocket to avoid that gravity assist would have added a few hundreds of millions to the cost of the Osiris-REx mission.

Answer (score 5):

Money. Why spend more if you don't have to? Especially if you're in a competition with other similar proposals. Which it was.